# Understanding Android Linear Layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

After extensive searching about linear layouts and how to accomplish position tasks with linear layouts I have found tons of questions with the popular answer being, "Use a relative layout".

I would like to understand linear layouts in depth and have had trouble finding an explanation that solves a task I feel like should be simple. Also a solution that makes sense seems reasonable.

If I was thinking of a screen as a tic tac toe board and wanted to position a button in each position how could I do this without relying on the width of the previous button for stacking or margins.

For example if I wanted to skip a spot in the square the spot I skip would stay empty.

```
{1} {2} {3}
{4} {5} {6}
{7} {8} {9}
```

From what I read my XML should position my buttons in 1 3 5 7 9 
but that is not that outcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:text="@string/btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:text="@string/btn2" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btn3" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="@string/btn4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="@string/btn5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:background="@drawable/background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My results are,

```
{1} {2} { }
{ } {5} { }
{7} {8} { }
```

I am so close to having this down! (I think...)

What am I missing to move 2 and 8 to the right one space? Am I not using linear layout as directed?

This is my objective.

```
{1} { } {2}
{ } { } { }
{ } { } { }
{ } {3} { }
{ } { } { }
{ } { } { }
{4} { } {5}
```

Comment: If you have so many horizontal and vertical views why don't you use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: Because I am trying to learn how to use linear layouts.

Comment: This kind of layout will have performance impact as it will take time to calculate screen density for each layout and there are so many. Better try different approach learning `LinearLayouts`.

Comment: I am not trying to build a enterprise application. i am trying to understand how linear layouts work in depth. I do not believe the solution to every question I find on the internet about linear layouts is, "Use a relative layout".  I just want to learn to control them so when I do make an enterprise application and I need a linear layout I will be able to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a straightforward answer to this is genuinely because LinearLayout isn't a good way of doing what you're trying to do.

As your objective is to understand LinearLayout and not really about achieving the final outcome I'll comment on a few things I've noted.

A key point here is the use of `layout_gravity`. It is not going to do what you want it to. In a LinearLayout, `layout_gravity` only works in one orientation at a time. In a horizontal LinearLayout the `layout_gravity` only affects the placement of the element *vertically*, and in a vertical LinearLayout the `layout_gravity` only affects the elements *horizontal* position. So you can't make a horizontal LinearLayout, put two buttons in it and use layout_gravity to make one stay left and the other stay right.

In a LinearLayout, the children are always placed one straight after another(either left to right or top to bottom) in the order that they are entered in the xml layout. So how do you create the gap?

There are two main ways that spring to mind:

You could use `layout_margin`. This defines an amount of space to leave clear outside a particular element, like a button. So if you wanted a gap of 100dp between button 1 and button 2, you could add `android:layout_marginRight="100dp"` to button 1, or you could add 50dp to the right of button 1 and 50dp to the left of button 2.

Another way would be to include a blank View of width 100dp to leave that space.
Here's your layout amended to show both those methods in practice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/myLayout" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn1" 
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn4" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn5" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:background="@drawable/background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, the ImageView. It wasn't specifically mentioned so I may be wrong about this, but since the drawable name is background I'm guessing that maybe it's intended that these buttons show in front of the ImageView. If that's the case, then it's worth mentioning that children in LinearLayouts *do not overlap*. That ImageView will always come after the layouts with the buttons. If you do want a background behind the buttons, you could add a background to the parent LinearLayout itself by adding `android:background="@drawable/background"` to the opening tag of the parent LinearLayout(though it might be stretched) or you could use a different type of layout that does allow overlapping.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. And yes I accidently left the background in the code when I copied it over but I am glad I did cause your explanation just makes the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

For tic-tac-toe, you need to reserve space for each button but the text will have an X or an O or a space. This will solve any issues with formatting.

I'm not clear on what your objective is.

Are you trying to do a tic-tac-toe for an X by X grid? If so, my point above still applies.

Comment: Please see the example of my objective at the bottom of my question. I want to be able to position buttons on a linear layout top-right top-left center-center bottom-left bottom-right

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Layouts horizontal and vertical as you know. İn addition, you can apply layout weight to make layouts with same size to cover full screen. For the condition you can use 3 vertical linear layouts with full height and same weights to cover the screen. Then you can fill their inside with full width buttons with same weight based on numbers you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for :

[image: for ur 7 x 3 matrix style button arragement]

it's xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{1}"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/b1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{2}"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/b3" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b6" />

</LinearLayout><LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b7" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b8" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b9" />
</LinearLayout><LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b10" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="{3}"
    android:id="@+id/b11" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b12" />   </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b13" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b14" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/b15" /></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b16" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b17" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b18" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{4}"
        android:id="@+id/b19" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/b20" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{5}"
        android:id="@+id/b21" /> </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

And for :

[image]

For its xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{1}"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/b1" />
       <android.support.v4.widget.Space
           android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="{2}"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/b3" />
    </LinearLayout>  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
  <android.support.v4.widget.Space
      android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="{3}"
    android:id="@+id/b11" />
  <android.support.v4.widget.Space
      android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{4}"
        android:id="@+id/b19" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{5}"
        android:id="@+id/b21" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Difference b/w 1st and 2nd is:
in 1st we use button with invisiblity..
in 2nd we use space ...
in 1st we cannt use space for whole line (means for all 3 button cannt be replce by space..if we doing that then it will be stack at the end of page with blank spce..it will not put space in b/w two lines.